# First checkbox is always checked in config form

Tags: forms, 9

I'm making config form with checkboxes and I'm always getting first checkbox checked. But in Kint debug it is not checked:

[image]

[image]

Here is part of my code:

```
$user_roles = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user_role')->loadMultiple();
$user_roles_indexed_array = [];
foreach ($user_roles as $user_role) {
  $user_roles_indexed_array[] = $user_role->label();
}
$form['restricted_user_roles_' . $content_type->id()] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $user_roles_indexed_array,
  '#default_value' => $config->get('restricted_user_roles_' . $content_type->id()) ? $config->get('restricted_user_roles_' . $content_type->id()) : [],
];
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I get solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2022-06-07/first-checkbox-is-always-checked-in-config-form#comment-14555859)

This first part of code was wrong, it refers to default value:

```
        $form['restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id()] =
    [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => $user_roles_indexed_array,
      '#default_value' => $config->get('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id()) ? $config->get('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id()) : [],
    ];
```

I changed it to this:

```
      $form['restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id()] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $user_roles_indexed_array,
    '#default_value' => $config->get('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id()) ?? [],
  ];
```

Also, second part of my code was wrong, it refers to submit:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) 
{  
$content_types = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();  
foreach ($content_types as $content_type)  
{    
$this->config('ctarpr.settings')      
->set('content_type_'.$content_type->label(), $form_state->getValue('content_type_'.$content_type->label()))
->set('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->label(), $form_state->getValue('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->label()))
->set('page_redirection_'.$content_type->label(), $form_state->getValue('page_redirection_'.$content_type->label()))
->save();  
}  
parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
   public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
$content_types = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();

foreach ($content_types as $content_type) {
  $this->config('ctarpr.settings')->set('content_type_'.$content_type->id(), $form_state->getValue('content_type_'.$content_type->id()));
  $this->config('ctarpr.settings')->set('page_redirection_'.$content_type->id(), $form_state->getValue('page_redirection_'.$content_type->id()));
  // Create the array of indexes of selected items (checked checkboxes).
  $restricted_roles = $form_state->getValue('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id());
  $restricted_roles = array_values($restricted_roles);
  foreach (array_keys($restricted_roles, 0, true) as $key) {
    unset($restricted_roles[$key]);
  }

  $this->config('ctarpr.settings')->set('restricted_user_roles_'.$content_type->id(), $restricted_roles);
  $this->config('ctarpr.settings')->save();
}
parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```